# MongoDB restart with no logs

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Why would mongodb randomly restart? Where can I look for details?

Using mongo 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

The first line of the log file is just
`2018-10-11T00:21:01.610+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****` and there are no other log files.

There is plenty of hard drive space and there were no CPU spikes before the restart. This server is a pure backup server (no clients connect to it, and its invisible to the other members)

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case. I figure this out 5 minutes afte posting it. The server ran out of memory (not sure why) and caused the restart. `journalctl` had the answers